# creating and populating table using pl/sql

Tags: database-design, oracle-11g, plsql, table

I have been looking for a way to create a table in pl/sql format like using DECLARE and BEGIN. Below is what i tried in sql Developer and but continiously getting the error below.

Please advise what am i doing wrong and if any good resource to learn on populating table using pl/sql? cheers!!

***Error report*** : ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:***

- begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
- raise return select update while with an identifier

`Code : 
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE 
    v_customer_ID  VARCHAR(10) not null := 3025;
    v_customer_Name VARCHAR(15) :='Michel Jackson' ;
    v_room_code  VARCHAR(5) := 6536;
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
( v_customer_id VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  v_customer_name varchar2(15),
  v_room_code varchar2(5),
  CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (v_customer_ID)
);
 END;
 /`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to use execute immediate. Check [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37362/why-cant-we-write-ddl-statement-directly-into-the-pl-sql-block)

```
DECLARE 
    v_customer_ID  VARCHAR(10) not null := 3025;
    v_customer_Name VARCHAR(15) :='Michel Jackson' ;
    v_room_code  VARCHAR(5) := 6536;
BEGIN

  execute immediate 'create table customer....';

END;
/
```

Comment: i am trying to populate this table using a procedure so i can do it for 50-100 numbers of rows. Could you please advise with some ideas or examples? Cheers!!

Comment: @klamgade Random data, data from other table?

Comment: For adding random data. I have created a separate question for it . [ http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147955/creating-stored-procedure-to-populate-empty-table-using-pl-sql/147956#147956 ] ..  Example here actually works, however, please suggest if any idea for placing correct Branch_ID and Boolean value for Is_Booked column?