# creating stored procedure to populate empty table using pl/sql

Tags: oracle, trigger, oracle-11g, plsql

I have created a table and inserted a values one row at a time. However, I am trying to **populate the table** using a "**stored procedure**" or "**trigger**". The values can be a random string or number. I have been researching on it, but couldn't find any related examples.

Could some please provide an example or suggest some reference to it? Cheers!!

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING 
(
  BOOKING_ID VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY
, BOOKING_DATE DATE 
, BRANCH_ID VARCHAR2(7) 
, ROOM_PRICE NUMBER(15) 
, IS_BOOKED VARCHAR(5))
TABLESPACE TS02
PCTFREE 20  PCTUSED 70
STORAGE (INITIAL 200K NEXT 500K PCTINCREASE 20);

--to insert value to BOOKING table for one row per at a time
INSERT INTO BOOKING
VALUES ('HIM001','02-FEB-2016','KTM',500,'NO');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with simple SQL statements and [DBMS_RANDON](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_random.htm#ARPLS040) as demonstrated below:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOKING 
(
  BOOKING_ID VARCHAR2(7) PRIMARY KEY, BOOKING_DATE DATE 
, BRANCH_ID VARCHAR2(7) 
, ROOM_PRICE NUMBER(15) 
, IS_BOOKED VARCHAR(5));



--You may create a sequence object to generate IDs. 
CREATE SEQUENCE booking_id_seq
 START WITH     1
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

INSERT INTO booking
SELECT booking_id_seq.nextval, TRUNC(SYSDATE + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,366)),
dbms_random.string('U',trunc(dbms_random.value(1,7))), trunc(dbms_random.value(1000,100000)), dbms_random.string('U',trunc(dbms_random.value(1,5)))
FROM  dual
CONNECT BY level <= 12;-- Here you can define the number of rows that you want to insert.




SQL> INSERT INTO booking
SELECT booking_id_seq.nextval, TRUNC(SYSDATE + DBMS_RANDOM.value(0,366)),
dbms_random.string('U',trunc(dbms_random.value(1,7))), trunc(dbms_random.value(1000,100000)), dbms_random.string('U',trunc(dbms_random.value(1,5)))
FROM  dual
CONNECT BY level <= 12;  

12 rows created.

SQL> select * from booking;

BOOKING BOOKING_D BRANCH_ ROOM_PRICE IS_BO
------- --------- ------- ---------- -----
158     06-NOV-16 ULQXM        81615 SH
159     18-DEC-16 RTG          99655 XDY
160     15-JUN-17 UF           45335 MCY
161     01-JUL-17 I            23249 FGS
162     13-MAY-17 KLLL          2177 T
163     07-AUG-17 HFC          10259 UKD
164     12-FEB-17 TVIZQY       98038 PJL
165     10-JUN-17 BIP          94314 ZSRS
166     22-JUL-17 ERQO         45985 QYC
167     27-AUG-16 EJKYB        39139 NJO
168     12-APR-17 AASMB        86838 NY

BOOKING BOOKING_D BRANCH_ ROOM_PRICE IS_BO
------- --------- ------- ---------- -----
169     24-FEB-17 NCQPMS       38296 Z

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dbms_random) are some good examples of using DBMS_RANDOM PL/SQL Package.

Comment: Wow!!! this example will be really helpful to get start with and will also check the reference provided. Appreciate that!!

Comment: I played around with the above code and created a procedure and executed it, which works fine. However, I am required to make the script robust enough so it can be reused on a daily basis without a need for modification. I am not sure what does that actually mean. Please advise if any idea. 

`CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE load_branch_values
 IS 
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO branch 
SELECT booking_id_seq.nextval,dbms_random.string( ...... then used execute load_branch_values ; `